# Changing the Location of Python Expressions QGIS3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgis-python-console

I've recently started using QGIS and I've written a few custom functions to use with expressions in the Function Editor (see image below)

[image: QGIS Function Editor]

From what I can find these appear to be saved in:

*C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\expressions*

I would like to share these with my colleagues. Is it possible to simply change the location these custom expression functions are read from? Or add another location they could be read from?

I would prefer the latter so that everyone could have access to the same general custom functions while still being able to access/write their own custom functions without everyone else having access to them.